# A simpler way to minimize the mean of squares, given the mean?

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have $N$ real numbers and I already know their mean, $\bar{x}$:

$$
\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i
$$

(but I don't know the individual values $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N)$.

I want to find the smallest possible value of the mean of the squares, $y$:
$$
y=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2
$$

I thought a bit about the case where $N=2$ and it seemed like the answer should be $x_1=x_2=\bar{x}$. For example, if $\bar{x}=5$, then $5^2+5^2=50$, but $4^2+6^2=52$ and $3^2+7^2=58$, and so on.

I feel like this should be a very simple thing to prove for any $N$, but I had to dig into the back of an old (engineering) [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0085AY57Q) to recall the method of Lagrange multipliers... which (unless I made a mistake) indeed gave me the answer $x_1=x_2=x_3=\dots=x_N=\bar{x}$. Or, using the vector notation of the textbook: $\underline{x}=\bar{x}\underline{1}$. I wrote my calculations below, just in case this result is wrong.

**My question is**: Is there a "simpler" way to prove this result (e.g. using basic high school mathematics)? Is it over-complicated to view this as a constrained optimization problem?

Many thanks for any help.

### My Calculations:

Function to minimize (subject to constraint): $$f(\underline{x})=\frac{1}{N}\underline{1}^T\underline{x}^2$$

Constraint: $$c(\underline{x})=\frac{1}{N}\underline{1}^T\underline{x}-\bar{x}=0$$

Unconstrained function to minimize: $$h(\underline{x})=f(\underline{x})+\lambda c(\underline{x})$$

Minimize to get $\lambda$: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \underline{x}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{x}}\left( \lambda c(\underline{x}) \right) = \underline{0}$$
$$\frac{2}{N}\underline{x} + \frac{\lambda}{N}\underline{1} = \underline{0}$$
$$\frac{2}{N}\underline{1}^T\underline{x} + \frac{\lambda}{N}\underline{1}^T\underline{1} = 0$$
$$\lambda = -2\bar{x}$$
Substitute $\lambda$ back in to solve for $x$:
$$\frac{2}{N}\underline{x} = \frac{2\bar{x}}{N}\underline{1}$$
$$\underline{x} = \bar{x}\underline{1}$$

Comment: See the RMS-AM inequality ([root mean square](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) a.k.a. [quadratic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noted, the mean of the square of a pair of numbers withe fixed average is attained when both are of equal magnitude.  Therefore for any finite set of numbers the same is true, since if two numbers in the set are different, they can be replaced by a better pair.  Given that the set is finite, a finite number of steps will suffice.

More direct approach - proof by contradiction: Assume $\sum x^2_i$ is minimum with $x_i^2\ne x_j^2$ for some $i\ne j$.  Replace pair with terms of equal average magnitude.  The sum will be lower, contradicting minimum assumption.

Comment: Ah, that's a clever way to think about it. I still had some trouble just proving it for the $N=2$ case... but I think I'm right in saying the two values must be symmetrical about the mean, so $x_1=\bar{x} + \alpha$ and $x_2=\bar{x} - \alpha$ (for some $\alpha$). Then the sum of the squares is $y = x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 2(\bar{x}^2 + \alpha^2)$ (hence the values 50, 52 and 58 in my example). Then this is clearly minimized by choosing $\alpha=0$.

Comment: In fact, I think this generalizes easily. I can simply write $\underline{x}=\bar{x}\underline{1} + \underline{\alpha}$, for some vector $\underline{\alpha}$ which must sum to zero in order for $\bar{x}$ to remain as the mean (so $\underline{1}^T\underline{\alpha} = 0$). Then I want to minimize $Ny=\underline{x}^T\underline{x}=N\bar{x}^2 + \bar{x}\underline{1}^T\underline{\alpha} + \bar{x}\underline{\alpha}^T\underline{1}+\underline{\alpha}^T\underline{\alpha} = N\bar{x}^2 + \underline{\alpha}^T\underline{\alpha}$, which is obviously minimized when $\underline{\alpha} = \underline{0}$.

Comment: @Harry I added a simpler proof to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this short enough?

- Take your $N$ values as the population so $E[X]=\frac1n \sum x_i =\bar x$.
- $\frac1n \sum x_i^2 = E[X^2]=(E[X])^2+\text{var}(X)$.
- $\text{var}(X)\ge 0$ with equality iff $X=E[X]$.
- So $\frac1n \sum x_i^2 =\left(\frac1n \sum x_i\right)^2 =\bar x ^2$ is the minimum given $\bar x$ the mean and occurs iff each $x_i=\bar x$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the notation. Is $X$ a random variable? I hadn't quite imagined that anything was random. Or does $X$ correspond to the set of $x_i$ values, for $i=1,2,\dots,N$? (Like the vector $\underline{x}$ in the question).

Comment: @Harry I was treating $X$ as a single random sample from the $x_i$s so its expectation is their mean and its variance is their variance etc.  Then using a well known expression relation the second moment to the variance and saying the second moment is minimised when the variance is $0$

Comment: Aha... then I think this may be equivalent to the solution I stumbled upon in my response to herb steinberg. I think you are defining $var(X)$ as something like $\lVert \underline{x} - \bar{x}\underline{1} \rVert^2$, which corresponds to $\underline{\alpha}^T\underline{\alpha}$ in my solution.